# Create user that has permission only to given database

Tags: permissions, marklogic

I'm trying to create users in MarkLogic that have permissions to given databases. I read [Security Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security) from MarkLogic docs page and found that you can set permissions on given URIs, Collections or functions.

Permissions on collections can help me with marking given collections from database as readable only for given set of users, but still other users can create and modify documents in different collections (or create documents without collections).

For e.g.

I have two databases:

- Test
- Test2

And two users:

- UserTest
- UserTest2

How can I set permissions that `UserTest` will have permissions read/update/insert/execute on database `Test` and can't modify or read anything database `Test2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each database can be associated with a dedicated security database. The way you describe your use case ("UserTest will have permissions read/update/insert/execute on database Test and can't modify or read anything database Test2"), you might want to consider dedicated security databases for the Test and Test2 databases.

The other way would be to use different *document* permissions for roles for the two databases. You can set read/update/insert/execute permissions at document level for a given role at insert time, or change them with xdmp:document-add-permissions() (retains previous permissions) or xdmp:document-set-permissions() (overrides previous permissions) after insert. For instance, you could have a role Test-Reader for database Test and a role Test2-Reader for database Test2, and ensure that (1) your UserTest user has the Test-Reader role (but not the Test2-Reader role), and (2) that all documents inserted into the Test database pair the read capability with the Test-Reader role (but not the Test2-Reader role) etc. (Same for the other capabilities.)

If controlling this explicitly sounds like a lot of work, note that default document permissions can be declared to apply implicitly both at the user and at the role level.

Finally, if you set no permissions at all during document insert (and if no implicit/default permissions are defined at user or role level), only users with the admin role can read/update/insert/execute.

Here's the relevant section for document permissions from the *Understanding and Using Security Guide*: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/permissions#id_85471

Answer (score 0):

There is no user-level specifications for a database. But keep in mind, a database is not accessible on its own - it is accessible by way of an application(s) which is linked to particular database. Unless you allow people to run eval and allow them to eval against another database, then you application will keep people within the specified database. (Note: ML8 Advanced HTTP server changes this a bit because you can switch database on-the-fly per request- but the rules about being stuck to a single database still stands).

The only other item I think is useful to you is the ability to define which URI prefixes a user can write to, but that does not negate the fact that the application level decided which DB is being accessed.